# Trying to integrate Elm with out legacy Rails 3 app but I keep seeing Elm not defined in Chrome console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elm, brunch

I use brunch and the final .js I got doesn't have things like var _user$project$MainApp$getPosition = function (_p0) {

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, I should have added elmBrunch's outputFolder directory to watched paths

like this :

```
watched: [
  "app",
  "public/vendor",
  "../elm"
],
```

"public/vendor" is the outputFolder directory of elmBrunch

"app" is the js where you call embed function

"../elm" obviously is the source code of elm